# HTML Table (APEX classic report) Column Header or background image

Tags: html, css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a bit of a strange issue.  I have a HTML table (Oracle APEX 5 classic report) using oracle identifiers as headers.

One particular header needs to be displayed as:

```
----------------------
-                One -
-                    -
-        Two         -
----------------------
```

I only have 30 characters to work with (because of the identifier length) so creating two spans and positioning them won't work.

I'm leaning towards the only way being creating an image of my cell and using it as the background-image.  However, I have tried the following and it didn't work:

```
   background-image: url('#APP_IMAGES#h.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

So, can anyone either help me apply a background image to a table header cell or point me towards another way of doing this?

Comment: I haven't worked with Oracle Apex before, so I'm confused about the question.  Can you provide an example of the HTML it generates in this situation, so we know what we have to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Dinamic Action that executes on Page Load and runs the following JQuery replacing the `COLUMN_NAME` with the actual column name (the ID of the TH if you inspect the column):

```
$('#COLUMN_NAME').css("background-image", "url(http://miniurl.me/themes/v3/images/facebook_icon.svg)");
```